# What do I do or where do I go to get people to join my chat room?

Tags: discussion, macos

I don't know who to invite to my chat room for help setting up a vm through VirtualBox. How do I find people to invite to that chatroom? How do I know who is the right people to invite to that chat room? How do I invite Ask different users to my chatroom?

This is my chatroom: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110760/macos-virtualbox-setup-help

Answer (score 1):

Adding a link to the chat room in the question might help, or mentioning it in the main chat. Or, of course, asking specific questions on the main site when you are stuck.

PS: Use @USERNAME in chat to ping people.

Comment: Is this the main chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38/ask-different-chat ?

Comment: @arien Yeah, that‘s right